# QPainter doesn't change color

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm learning `Qt`. I'm failing to realize [the exercise of chapter 11 of Qt tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.3/tutorial-t11.html), which states "Change the color of the cannon when a shot is in the air." I chose to implement the change in paintCannon function (below). What's wrong with my code below?

```
void CannonField::paintCannon(QPainter &painter)
{
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    if (autoShootTimer->isActive()){

        std::cout << "in paintCannon yellow; "  << std::endl; 
        // This gets called everytime `paintEvent` occurs. 
        // Please see the code in the web page (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial-t11-cannonfield-cpp.html) for this part.

        painter.setBrush(Qt::yellow);
    }else{
        std::cout << "in paintCannon blue; "  << std::endl;
        painter.setBrush(Qt::blue);
    }

    painter.save();
    painter.translate(0, height());
    painter.drawPie(QRect(-35, -35, 70, 70), 0, 90 * 16);
    painter.rotate(-currentAngle);
    painter.drawRect(barrelRect);
    painter.restore();
}
```

Since I first suspected `Qpainter`'s `save` and `restore` might have been doing something wrong, I commented them out which ended up re-painting nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: What color is the cannon that does get drawn?

Comment: What does your code do? How does this differ from what it ought to do? Does it, e.g., output `in PaintCannon blue` (or `yellow`) but then use a different colour, or what?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner The cannon remains blue, which is the color initially drawn.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan what this code does might been clear if you look at the code I refer to; what I intend is, at normal state the cannon is in blue. Only while a shot is in the air the cannon get drawn yellow.

Comment: That tut is very outdated, I'd look up something [more recent](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book?hsLang=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is in this routine:

```
void CannonField::moveShot()
{
    QRegion region = shotRect();
    ++timerCount;

    QRect shotR = shotRect();

    if (shotR.x() > width() || shotR.y() > height())
    {
        autoShootTimer->stop();
    } 
    else
    {
        region = region.unite(shotR);
    }
    update(region);
}
```

When the shot is moved, `update()` is being called with a region specified. This results in only the shot rectangle being repainted. If you remove the region from the call to `update()`, the entire widget is repainted and your color change will work correctly.